# Cycle columns of a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I have a problem that is asking me to cycle columns of a MxN matrix Z number of times. The code I have currently is below but when I run it some of the columns disappear.

My code should move the first column into the second, the second into the third etc and then the last into the first column.

```
int first[5][5], second[5][5], i, j;    

int temp[5][5];
       for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < numprocs; j++){
            temp[i][j] = second[i][j];
            second[i][j] = second[i--][j];
            second[i++][j] = temp[i][j];
         }
       }
```

Comment: Show declarations , initializations

Comment: Please, what are we supposed to do with this. What are `m`, `n` ? What are their values with respect to `numprocs`? What is `myid`? Voting to close because your are missing an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And your problem are most likely the abuses of `++` and `--` inside array designators. Your are changing your loop variables.

Comment: Instead of copying values, consider an approach that wraps around an MxN data structure, where the "first" value in a matrix can be at some offset i x j, and data are printed out from that offset *mod* row and *mod* column.

Comment: @AlexReynolds okay I will try and work that out

Comment: Based on usage temp needn't be an array--you're just using it as temp storage to do an element swap.  Define temp to be _int temp_ and replace all _temp[i][j]_ with _temp_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no need to have a duplicate array of *entire* size. You can cycle the elements in one array itself. Try it on a piece of paper.
- You'll need to take backup of the 1st column every time, because that will be overwritten. Then, restore this backup.

I did it using simple array and some looping. Have a look at the code, it's self explanatory, and I've commented appropriately:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define M 2 //no of rows
#define N 5 //no of columns

int print(int (*matrix)[N]);

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[M][N];
    int backup[M];

    int Z; //no of times to cycle
    int i, j, k;

    //get the i/p
    printf("Enter matrix:\n");
    for(i = 0 ; i < M ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);

    //get Z
    printf("How many times to cycle?\n");
    scanf("%d", &Z);

    //for Z = 0
    if(Z == 0)
    {
        print(matrix);
        return 0;
    }



    Z = (Z%N);  //adjust Z to avoid unnecessary rotations because
//rotating an array of 5 columns 25 times is same as rotating 0 times
//(it will end up in original position after 25 rotations)

    for(k = 0 ; k < Z ; k++)    //first loop for Z rotations
    {
        //take backup of 1st col of matrix
        for(int i = 0 ; i < M ; i++)
        backup[i] = matrix[i][0];

        for(i = N - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)   //second loop for copying each column
        {
            //copy ith column into (i+1)%n th column
            for(j = 0 ; j < M ; j++)        //loop to copy all elements of column
            {
                matrix[j][(i+1)%N] = matrix[j][i];  //logic to wrap the last col to first one
            }
        }

        //restore backup into 1st col
        for(j = 0 ; j < M ; j++)
            matrix[j][1] = backup[j];

    }

    print(matrix);
}

int print(int (*matrix)[N])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0 ; i < M ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is a run of the sample program:

```
Enter matrix:
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
How many times to cycle?
1
5 1 2 3 4 
5 1 2 3 4 
aditya@aditya-laptop:~/Desktop$  cc so.c -std=c11&& ./a.out
Enter matrix:
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
How many times to cycle?
3
3 4 5 1 2 
3 4 5 1 2
```