# how to understand these code which rearrange (a1 a2...am b1 b2..bn ) in an array to(b1 b2 ..bn a1 a2..am)

Tags: c, algorithm

This code is designed by someone to change array `[a1 a2...am b1 b2..bn ]` to the array `[b1 b2 ..bn a1 a2..am]`, but it involves the greatest common divisor which I can't get the point.

```
void Exchange(int a[],int m,int n,int s){
    int p=m,temp=m+n;int k=s%p;
    while(k!=0){temp=p;p=k;k=temp%p;}
    for(k=0 ; k<p ;k++){                //below is where i cant't understand
        temp=a[k];i=k;j=(i+m)%(m+n);
        while(j!=k)
            {a[i]=a[j];i=j;j=(j+m)%(m+n);}
        a[i]=temp;
    }
};
```

EDIT: "Properly" indented:

```
void Exchange(int a[], int m, int n, int s) {
    int p = m, temp = m + n, k = s % p;

    while (k != 0) {
        temp = p;
        p = k;
        k = temp % p;
    }

    for (k = 0 ; k < p; k ++) {   // below is where i cant't understand
        temp = a[k];
        i = k;
        j = (i + m) % (m + n);

        while (j != k) {
            a[i] = a[j];
            i = j;
            j = (j + m) % (m + n);
        }

        a[i] = temp;
    }
};
```

Comment: Which programming language did you use? Please add an appropiate tag. You can do that by click on the edit link.

Comment: I would kick this "someone" out of the C league for such a code...

Comment: And what is `s`? It is not defined.

Comment: Yes,it a default,but what i want to know is its idea and mechanism

Comment: Adding `s` to the parameters list is not adding to it's meaning.

Comment: Had to add an alternative with a "more readable" indentation. Otherwise nobody will look into it.

Comment: variable names need to indicate `content` or `usage` (or better both).  the posted variable names:  `a[]`, `m`, `n`, `s`  `p` temp`, `k` are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) properly indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. never use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest 4 spaces per indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: we also have a very difficult time understanding what the objective of the code is.  This is mostly due to poor formatting and meaningless variable names  We could figure it out, by spending some hours on it. but why should we bother to try and understand some very poorly written code.  Anything we can do, you can do just as easily.

Comment: there are the variables `i` and `j`, but they are not declared anywhere within the posted code.

Comment: So in order for the function to behave as described in your question, the parameter `s` has to be set to `m + n`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using a single value of overhead to implement array rotation. If the lengths are mutually prime, a single pass suffices. If not, you have to repeat the shift cycle by the GCD of the lengths

I said earlier that there are other questions on SO that cover this.  A look found [SO 3333-3814](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33338314) which deals with a single rotation.  I did some messing with code to support that a while ago, demonstrating the need for GCD, but I didn't previously post it.

Here's the code — it uses C99 VLAs — variable length arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int r;

    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
        return(0);

    while ((r = x % y) != 0)
    {
        x = y;
        y = r;
    }
    return(y);
}

static void dump_matrix(int m, int n, int source[m][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%4d", source[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static void init_matrix(int m, int n, int source[m][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            source[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 2);
    }
}

static void rotate_1col(int n, int vector[n], int z)
{
    z %= n;
    if (z != 0)
    {
        int c = gcd(n, z);
        int s = n / c;
        for (int r = 0; r < c; r++)
        {
            int x = r;
            int t = vector[x];
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            {
                int j = (x + z) % n;
                int v = vector[j];
                vector[j] = t;
                x = j;
                t = v;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void rotate_cols(int m, int n, int source[m][n], int z)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        rotate_1col(n, source[i], z);
}

int main(void)
{
    int m = 3;

    for (int n = 2; n < 9; n++)
    {
        int source[m][n];
        for (int z = 0; z <= n; z++)
        {
            init_matrix(m, n, source);
            printf("Initial:\n");
            dump_matrix(m, n, source);
            rotate_cols(m, n, source, z);
            printf("Post-rotate %d:\n", z);
            dump_matrix(m, n, source);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code demonstrates different sizes of rotation on different sizes of array.  Example sections of the output:

```
…
Initial:
   2   3   4
   4   6   8
   6   9  12
Post-rotate 1:
   4   2   3
   8   4   6
  12   6   9
…
Initial:
   2   3   4   5
   4   6   8  10
   6   9  12  15
Post-rotate 3:
   3   4   5   2
   6   8  10   4
   9  12  15   6
…
Initial:
   2   3   4   5   6   7
   4   6   8  10  12  14
   6   9  12  15  18  21
Post-rotate 1:
   7   2   3   4   5   6
  14   4   6   8  10  12
  21   6   9  12  15  18

Initial:
   2   3   4   5   6   7
   4   6   8  10  12  14
   6   9  12  15  18  21
Post-rotate 2:
   6   7   2   3   4   5
  12  14   4   6   8  10
  18  21   6   9  12  15

Initial:
   2   3   4   5   6   7
   4   6   8  10  12  14
   6   9  12  15  18  21
Post-rotate 3:
   5   6   7   2   3   4
  10  12  14   4   6   8
  15  18  21   6   9  12
…
Initial:
   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27
Post-rotate 4:
   6   7   8   9   2   3   4   5
  12  14  16  18   4   6   8  10
  18  21  24  27   6   9  12  15

Initial:
   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27
Post-rotate 5:
   5   6   7   8   9   2   3   4
  10  12  14  16  18   4   6   8
  15  18  21  24  27   6   9  12

Initial:
   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27
Post-rotate 6:
   4   5   6   7   8   9   2   3
   8  10  12  14  16  18   4   6
  12  15  18  21  24  27   6   9
…
```

Comment: You get the point.But what i can't reach is how it exactly work using GCD

Comment: Suppose you have 8 entries in total and you want to shift by 5.  Because 8 and 5 are mutually prime, you can do the rotation in one cycle. If you want to shift by 4 instead, you have to rotate (swap) 0 and 4, 1 and 5, 2 and 6, and 3 and 7.  That's because GCD(8, 4) is 4.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get the result you said you expected, I have set m and n to be half the array size. I also assumed that s would be initialised to zero, in which case, the first while loop does not iterate. Also, there are several declarations missing in your code so my explanation makes some assumptions.

```
The variable p holds the number of array elements to swap;


// This is to keep the value to be overwritten by the swap  
temp=a[k];

// This is the array index of the bottom half element to write the top half element to
i=k;

// this is to get the current index of the top half; 
j=(i+m)%(m+n);

// This assignes the bottom index value with the top half value
while(j!=k)
    {
            // Write top half element to corresponding bottom half element
            a[i]=a[j];
            // We can now overwrite top half element; this assignes the index at wich to copy the bottom half element
            i=j;
            // This is to get out of the loop
            j=(j+m)%(m+n);
    }

 // The bottom half element held at the beginning is now written to the top half at the corresponding index
 a[i]=temp;
```

Hope this is the answer you were looking for. I arrived at this result by using a debugger and by stepping in the code line by line. I don't know if you know how to use a debugger but if not, then I highly recommend your lean how to use one; it it time well spent and it returns an awesome dividend :-)